# "Mark as read" on shared Outlook mailbox doesn't update immediately for the whole team

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

In my job, where we respond to support requests from various users, we have a very antiquated system for raising support tickets. How it works is that the first person who opens the email in the shared team Outlook mailbox (we use the Outlook 365 desktop application) enters its contents into our call logging system. When the team member opens the email, it gets marked as read in Outlook, so other members of the team know that someone is in process of raising a support ticket.

However, the issue we often have is that when 2 people in our team open an email at the same time or within a few seconds of each other, we end up with 2 versions of the same support ticket being raised by 2 different team members. This is because Outlook sometimes takes a while to update, so an email still shows as unread even though someone else on the team has already opened it. What compounds the situation further is that in our call logging system, there is no way to tell that someone else in our team has started logging a call until they've actually finished entering it and clicked Save.

It's frustrating to raise a new support ticket and then find out a couple of minutes later that a co-worker has already just finished raising one about the same issue! In the worst case scenario, we've had 3 support tickets raised about the same issue.

We are due to change our call logging system soon (thankfully!), but in the meantime, is there any way to reduce this problem of duplicate support calls? Is there any way to make sure that when one team member opens an email in the shared Outlook mailbox, it marks that email as read in everyone else's Outlook immediately (rather than the current lag)? Or can you think of another way in which we can let the rest of the team know we've already opened the email?

Comment: I'm not aware of a good method as you already know, it will take sometime for Outlook to sync the read/unread status to Exchange server and then sync to other users' Outlook. Is it possible to have the people who has raised a new support ticket to send a notification email to the group?

Comment: Thanks Steve, but wouldn't sending a notification email to the group have the same problem - ie that it would take time for Outlook to sync and they might not see the email until it's too late?  I guess one other option could be to set up an internal chat group (like a Slack or WebEx Teams group chat) where people can send a notification when they're starting to raise a new support call.

Comment: Sounds good, Victoria. It would be a better way to set up an internal chat group.